# Alternative for DataGridView for presenting all the data at once

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Part of application I'm working with returns multiple datasets and we're showing them to users as many DataGridViews on one scrolling panel. The problem is - setting height of datagridview even with known amount of rows is not trivial (you can't easily tell DGV to resize to the size of the grid) and with our custom styling working with inner sizes of DGV didn't turn out well.
At the moment we're stuck with many DGVs - those that are supposed to keep lots of data are a bit higher, while those that possibly won't have data / have small amounts, are lower. Also every DGV has a label above, which splits the DGVs and labels current data. Next complication - I get all the DGVs data as separate DataTables.
What can I use to just show all the data, as in one big table with multiple subtables? Without even caring that some of them have different amount of rows or anything like it?

Comment: I presume that your grids have different column configurations?

Comment: I want to resize grids vertically, because I've got a few tens of them on one scrolling panel and some of them are almost empty, some of them have lots of rows and it looks confusing and unreadable.
Yes, grids have different column configurations.

Comment: Does it have to be a long list? Have you consider using multiple tab pages, or some sort of an [accordion control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416521/Easy-WinForms-Accordion-Control) ([another variant](http://jfblier.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/accordion-control/))?

Comment: It's a result page of physical parameters computing, it is a bit easier to use if it looks like a long sheet.

Comment: Maybe you could do this: put a TabControl(with tab pages as much as you need) on your Form than load single DataGridView in single UserControl and call that UserControl just by painting that tabPage.

Comment: also, my opinion on that long sheet that again it will be confusing.

Comment: Unfortunately it's already in TabControl, and it's not about changing the whole user experience, just about fixing this one thing. 
@Sylca: Depends on a scale and amounts of information, preferably for me the long sheet was just good - and people actually using that software didn't say a bad thing about prints (long excel files) from other parts of the system with very similar composition.

Comment: Wish I helped you in anyway.:-)Than I hope that you'll find alternative solution for your data preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used static (non-scrolled) custom grid for DataTables with small amount of rows and DataGridViews for those grids, that we'd like to scroll (enough rows). Something like: using DataGridView on aspx page for the scrolling ones, and `<table>` for the static ones.